# Trust him about as far as I can throw him?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Here is a quote from The Avengers, 2012 film.

> Coulson : But first, we need you to talk to the big guy.
>   Natasha : Coulson, you know that Stark trusts me *about* as far as he can throw me.
>   Coulson : I've got Stark. You get the big guy.

I know what "Stark trusts me as far as he can throw me" means: he doesn't trust me. But I'm not sure why the sentence includes *about*. What does *about* mean here?

Plus, What does *I've got Stark* mean in the exchange? Maybe Coulson meant *I will take on Stark*?

Answer (score 5):

> I trust him as far as I can throw him.

This does indeed mean I do not trust him very much (unless I am really big and strong, and he is quite small, and I could actually throw him quite far).

> I've got Stark.

Means indeed "I'll take him on".

"I've got it" or "I've got him" can indeed mean "I'll take care of it/him".

> Q: I can solve the first three issues, but what about the last one?
>   A: I've got it!

Means that the answerer will take care of that last issue.

Now for **about**:

That simply means "more or less" in this case. It is quite often used in this sense in sentences like these:

> He is about 5 foot 4.
>   When will you arrive? About three.